# What is the underlying database/ storage for Azure Time Series Insights?

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

Is there a way to access the storage directly? From the API docs only Query APIs have been released. I understand the use case for Time series is just for querying data and if there is any meta data that needs be changed, it can be done using the reference data.

Am I correct in my understanding or is there a way to Update the data for Time Series insights?

Answer (score 2):

@raga,

I'm a PM on Time Series Insights.  To access the underlying data, you can use our /events API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-reference-queryapi#get-environment-events-api).  Today, we don't support deletion or update operations, however it's on the roadmap and we will support it in the future, at least in our forthcoming features.  More on those here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/propel-your-iot-platform-to-the-cloud-with-azure-time-series-insights/

You're also right that metadata can be updated for new events using reference data.

I hope this helps.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. I got these documentation online. I was still wondering about the underlying database that time series use as I would need to make changes to the architecture.

Comment: Today we use a proprietary columnar store (SSD/In-memory).  We are adding Azure Blob storage as a second tier later this year.